# Bounding the growth/decay of a linear ODE system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-norms

Suppose we have a linear system of differential equations governed by a matrix $A$:

$$ \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = A\mathbf{x}, \ \mathbf{x}(t=0) = \mathbf{x}_0$$

We know that the solution is

$$ \mathbf{x}(t) = e^{At}\mathbf{x}_0. $$

Now define:

$$ D:= \frac{\|\mathbf{x(t)}\|}{\|\mathbf{x}_0\|} $$

I know that we can find an upper bound for $D$ as follows:

$$ \| \mathbf{x}(t) \| \leq \|e^{At}\| \|\mathbf{x}_0\| \leq e^{\|A\|t} \|\mathbf{x}_0\|  $$
$$ \therefore D \leq e^{\|A\|t}$$.

My question is: how can we find a lower bound for $D$? In the specific case I'm considering, $A$ is upper triangular (sometimes strictly upper triangular) and non-diagonalizable.

Comment: Why are you interested in a lower bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather simple to give a lower bound of the kind of your upper bound.

Indeed, since $\mathbf{x}_0=e^{-At}\mathbf{x}(t)$, similarly
$$
\|\mathbf{x}_0\|\le e^{\|A\|\cdot|t|} \|\mathbf{x}(t)\|\quad\Rightarrow\quad  \|\mathbf{x}(t)\|\ge e^{-\|A\|\cdot|t|}\|\mathbf{x}_0\|.
$$

You should also replace $t$ by $|t|$ in your question.